# SSRS Parameter Default to select all

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am currently have a Drug Name parameter that populates a list a drugs based on what stores are selected with the Store parameter.  The portion of the query below is what I am using for the dataset that populates the drug names.

```
 alter procedure SSRSReporting.Parameters_Get
    @ParameterName varchar(100),
    @StoreKey varchar(max) = NULL

as


    declare
        @ParameterNameLocal varchar(100),
        @StoreKeyLocal  varchar(max) = NULL

    select
        @ParameterNameLocal = @ParameterName,
        @StoreKeyLocal = @StoreKey

else if @ParameterNameLocal = 'GPIName'
        begin
            declare
                @StoreList table (StoreKey int)

            insert into @StoreList (StoreKey)
                select
                    convert(int,Name) 
                from 
                    SSRSReporting.SplitString (@StoreKeyLocal)
            select
                'All GPIs' as 'Label',
                null as 'Value',
                0 as 'OrderBy'

            union

            select
                DrugName as 'Label',
                GPI as 'Value',
                1 as 'OrderBy'
            from
                Final.FactRXBusinessEffectiveDay fact
                    inner join @StoreList sl
                        on fact.StoreKey = sl.StoreKey
                    inner join Final.DimDrug drug
                        on fact.DrugKey = drug.DrugKey and drug.DEAClass <> 'No DEA Class'
            order by
                'OrderBy',
                'Label'
        end
```

The main dataset contains the following code related to the Drug Name

```
declare @GPINameTable table
(
    GPI varchar(max)
)

if @GPINameLocal IS NOT NULL
begin
    --Multiselect GPIs
    insert into @GPINameTable (GPI)
    select
        Name
    from
        SSRSReporting.SplitString (@GPINameLocal)       
end

    where
        PharmTransDateKey between @StartDateLocal and @EndDateLocal
        and (@GPINameLocal is null or drug.GPI in (select GPI from @GPINameTable))
```

I currently have the Available and Default values for the Drug Name set to the Dataset that populates the drug name list.  I should also mention that the Drug List parameter needs to multi-select.

The problem is that nothing is selected after I choose the stores and the list populates.  How would I default to Select All?

Comment: You require a cascading set of parameters?

Comment: Yes, certain drugs will be listed depending on the store(s) that have been chosen.

Comment: Are your **DEFAULT values** the same as the Available **VALUE** (GPI?) and not the  LABEL?

Comment: @HannoverFist, Are you talking about the parameter settings in Visual Studio?  Under the General Tab I have it to allow multiples.  Available Values is set to my GPIName data set with Value field = Value and Label field = Label.  Under Defaults values I am using the same dataset with Value field = Value.

Comment: @Istaley - yes, the param settings. That is correct but I did just notice you add a SELECT **ALL** with **NULL** as the Value. The NULL will cause the Default not to work correctly. Try using a **xx** or **~** for the ALL value. Not sure why you need it if you are using Multi-Value.

Comment: @HannoverFist, sorry, do you mean something like select
                'All GPIs' as 'Label',
                xx as 'Value',
                0 as 'OrderBy'?

Comment: @Istaley - yes - I think the NULL is what is messing up your DEFAULT values. Use 'xx' or '~'

Comment: I thought that is what you meant, sorry.  Thanks for clarifying, unfortunatley I get an error message when the DrugName list populates.  "An error occurred during local report processing.  Cannot read the next data row for the dataset GPIName.  Error converting data type varchar to bigint".  I also tried just deleting the select statement with the NULL and leaving just leaving the other select statement.  This did indeed populate the parameter list but the browser froze up and needed to be killed.

Comment: Scratch that, what I tried only 'checked' some of the listed drugs, not all of them (weird).  Besides it also froze the browser up and needed to be killed.